# error connect in smb dir using jcifs

Tags: java, smb

If i try

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("cabanellos.local","deivisson.sedrez", "passs");
String path = "smb://fsct/scanpr$/test.txt";`
SmbFile sFile2 = new SmbFile(path, auth);    `
```

It connects and creates a file, but if i try:

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("cabanellos.local",  "deivisson.sedrez", "passs");
String path = "smb://fsct/scanpr$/"; 
SmbFile sFile2 = new SmbFile(path, auth);    
SmbFile[] varTeste = dir.listFiles();    
for(int i=0;i<varTeste.length;i++){
    if(varTeste[i].isFile()){                                    
         //site = new URL((Pasta_Financeiro + varTeste[i].getName()).toString()); 
         SmbFile dest = new SmbFile ("file:///"+Pasta_Financeiro + varTeste[i].getName());
         dir.copyTo(dest);
    }
}
```

I get this exception "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password." but all is correctly

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use "smb://"+Pasta_Financeiro instead of "file:///"+Pasta_Financeiro

Answer (score 0):

i use

`SmbFile remoteFile = new SmbFile("smb://...")`
`OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/local/file");`
`InputStream is = remoteFile.getInputStream();`
`int bufferSize = 1024;`
`byte[] b = new byte[bufferSize];`
`int noOfBytes = 0;`
`while( (noOfBytes = is.read(b)) != -1 )`
`{`
`os.write(b, 0, noOfBytes);`
`}`
`os.close();`
`is.close();`

also

`dir.copyTo(dest);`

and its works

ty for help